# Can't use classpath resource to paint JPanel as background picture

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, path, jpanel

Below is the class i intended to use for painting.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BackgroundMainMenu extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Image img;

      public BackgroundMainMenu(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
      }

      public BackgroundMainMenu(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
      }
}
```

I get the background when i use system path like below.

```
public class FirstWindow extends JFrame {

   public FirstWindow() {

   BackgroundMainMenu panel = new BackgroundMainMenu(newImageIcon("E:\\sources\\mainMenu.jpg").getImage());

   JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Program Window");
   mainFrame.getContentPane().add(panel); 
   mainFrame.pack();
   mainFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work when i use classpath resource. I tried changing this line

```
 this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
```

to this.

```
 this(new ImageIcon(FirstWindow.class.getResource(img)).getImage());
```

And this line

```
BackgroundMainMenu panel = new BackgroundMainMenu(new ImageIcon("E:\\sources\\mainMenu.jpg").getImage());
```

to this.

```
BackgroundMainMenu panel = new BackgroundMainMenu(newImageIcon(FirstWindow.class.getResource("/stuff/images/mainMenu.jpg")).getImage());
```

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to paint background using JPanel?

Comment: Show the result of `jar -tfv the.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BackgroundMainMenu(newImageIcon(FirstWindow.class.getResource("/stuff/images/mainMenu.jpg")).getImage());
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) for the basic example for loading a resource

A couple of points:

1. Is the "stuff" directory actually on your classpath?
2. Is the leading "/" needed?

Comment: 1. Yes it is.
2. I just tried without leading "/" and still nothing. I get the error:
javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
if it's gonna help

Comment: @JonathanP, The code works fine for me. I have an "image" sub directory as a child of the director where all my class files are located. If I give an incorrect filename I get a NullPointerException. So I don't know how my test code is different than yours. Don't tell us what you changed. Post the actual code that you tested. This code should include the main() method so we can copy/paste/test. In other words post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU! Problem was caused by the src folder inside my project which i had to include in the path. I'm sorry about the duplicate question, i'll delete it now.